# Align Two <div>s Without Parent Container

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm trying to position two `<div>` elements so that that their left sides line up, like the top navigation bar and sidebar in this photo:

[image: Enter your own goddamn description.]

Normally, I would use a parent `<div>` to help with this.  The problem is that I plan on using a PHP `include()` for the header and sidebar, to save copying and pasting across the site.  This means that the `<div>` tag has to be left open at the end of the `include()`, to leave room for the content on the right.  This seems like horrible practice, and I might forget to add `</div>` at the end of the page.

Is there a way to align the blocks without enclosing them in a parent container?

EDIT: Here's what I have so far.

```
<!-- Common code.  Designed to be include()'d into each page. -->
<div id = "Header">
    <a href = "/"><img id = "Logo" src = "Foo.jpg"></a>
    <!-- #Logo is centered in CSS. -->

    <ul id = "TopNav">
        <li><a href = "/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "Browse">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- #TopNav is also centered in CSS. There are also
    some fancy link effects, but those are irrelevant. -->
</div>

<div id = "Sidebar">
    <!-- Contains stuff like advertisements and a 
    table of contents. -->
</div>
<!-- No CSS effects are currently applied to the sidebar, meaning it's on the
far left of the page.  I'm trying to line it up with #TopNav, which is
closer to the center.

<!-- The content section to the right of the sidebar is not included
in this file.  That's defined on a page-by-page basis.  Whatever that
content is, it should fall to the right of the sidebar.  It'd be nice
if the left side of the content never fell past the right side of the
sidebar, though not an absolute necessity. -->
```

Comment: You should add a representation of your HTML structure.

Comment: @thirtydot I don't see how example code will help in this case.  All it would be is three `<div> <!-- ... --> </div>`s.

Comment: I see. What's supposed to be lining up? What's the "title bar"?

Comment: The reason for the request is because we can't make any assumptions on your markup. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/LXwmF/ . With very little CSS code, it already does what you want.

Comment: @thirtydot The two light blue bits in the photo.  "Title bar" means nav bar.  My mistake.

Comment: @ngen Alright, give me a moment to set up an example.

Comment: @maxpm: Am I getting confused? Why would you have to leave the `div` open? Can't you just write `<div id="parent"><?php include 'header_sidebar.php'; ?><div id="content"></div></div>`.

Comment: @tw16 Possibly because I'm coming from C++, and I'm used to *only* including stuff at the top of files.  Though I suppose that does work.

Comment: @maxpm: So shall I put it as an answer then? I.e. you can use parent container to align?

Comment: @tw16 Sure, I'll upvote it.  Just be careful it doesn't sound like you completely ignored the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still align the two `div`'s using a parent container. There is no need to worry about leaving `div` tags open. Just write your html/php like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <?php include 'header_sidebar.php'; ?>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The most sensible answer, who knew it was that simple?

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're after just clicked.

You can use the `body` element as your container for the three `div`s.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4st5e/

Though I'm still not sure why you can't just add a wrapper `div`..

Answer (score 0):

I've made this quick mock up: http://jsfiddle.net/LXwmF/1/

I don't know if that's how you currently have it setup but you could use mine as a template. You can see you can style each parent div.